# Best way to split a string by two different delimiters, capitalize the two words encasing either delimiter only, and adding both delimiters back in?

Tags: python, regex, string, delimiter

I'm writing a Python script that should be able to split a string by two delimiters: '_' and '.', capitalize both the words that are split by the delimiters (encasing the delimiters), and then finally have the delimiters placed back where they were.

So something like: `this_is.an_Example string for.You`

should turn into: `This_Is.An_Example string For.You`

Right now I have this: `return '_'.join(x.capitalize() for x in re.split('_|\.', str)) + '\n'` which is not really doing what I want it to.

Any clean ways of doing this?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: If your input string was `foo.bar bar_foo`, what would your desired output be?

Comment: It'd be Foo.Bar Bar_Foo :)

Comment: You should clarify that to the current answer, which doesn't follow that pattern

Comment: @user3483203 yep! I did in the comment below, thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
s = "this_is.an_Example string for.You"
print(re.sub( r'(?<![^_.])[^\W_]+|[^\W_]+(?=[._])', lambda x: x.group().capitalize(), s))
# => This_Is.An_Example string For.You
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/OQSEw2) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DdMQAM/1).

**Pattern details**

- `(?<![^_.])[^\W_]+` - 1 or more digit or letters (`[^\W_]+`) that are immediately preceded with `_`, or `.`, or start of string
- `|` - or
- `[^\W_]+(?=[._])` - 1 or more digit or letters (`[^\W_]+`) that are immediately followed with `_`, or `.`, or end of string.

Comment: I almost had the same here :) you can use `x.group().upper()` as well

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre True, just used what OP had, the approach remains the same.

Comment: This won't capitalize the `for`, although that's desired

Comment: @user3483203 Yeah, I am sure it is a typo in the expected output, I fixed it in the question. It is not in line with the requirements.

Comment: I'd wait for clarification before editing, I think it makes sense regarding the requirements.  It's one of the words split by a delimiter

Comment: @user3483203 Given the current code and problem, it is a typo.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It's exactly what I was looking for. I still don't understand it fully, but I'll stare at it for a while and see if I can. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: The lookbehind is a bit cryptic, but it is the only way in Python fixed-width lookbehinds.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, sorry to come back to this, but I'm trying to also add ’ to the delimiter list. I think I just don't understand regexes well enough to do this on my own. How can I change your answer to include this?

Comment: @x0xchoc0late Not sure what you mean. Maybe [this](https://regex101.com/r/DdMQAM/2) will help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry for yet another question, but it seems like this capitalizes one word strings too. How can I change it to capitalize _only_ the words separated by the 3 delimiters?

Comment: So what is the expected result for `this_is.an_Example string for.You'll know' 'em`?

Comment: That one looks fine, but when we try something like `this is_an.example string` it should look like `this Is_An.Example string` but instead it capitalizes the first word which does not have a delimiter, so it looks like `This Is_An.Example string`. @WiktorStribiżew